# Stop scroll on the end of the last <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kureiii/45Exw/

```
var cur = 1;
var max = $(".collectionsCnt2").children("li").length;

$(".button-right").click(function () {

if (cur + 1 > max) return;
cur++;

$(".collectionsCnt2").animate({
    marginLeft: "-=500px",
}, 1000);

});

(".button-left").click(function () {
if (cur - 1 < 1) return;
cur--;
$(".collectionsCnt2").animate({
    marginLeft: "+=500px",
}, 1000);

});
```

The scroll is working however I want the scroll to stop when it reach the last li or the last box?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
var cur = 1;
var max = $(".collectionsCnt2").children("li").length;

$(".button-right").click(function () {

    if (cur >= max) return;
        cur =  cur + (500/100 < max ? 500/100 : max);

        $(".collectionsCnt2").animate({
        marginLeft: "-=500px",
    }, 1000);

});

$(".button-left").click(function () {
    if (cur <= 1) return;
        cur =  cur - (500/100 < max ? 500/100 : max);
        $(".collectionsCnt2").animate({
            marginLeft: "+=500px",
        }, 1000);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45Exw/11/)

Instead of hard-coding the values, you can do this instead,

```
marginLeft: -$(".collectionsCnt2 li:last-child").offset().left + $(".collectionsCnt2")[0].scrollLeft -51 + 'px'
```